# Using a coordinate pair as a key in a Lua table

Tags: lua, lua-table

As the title says, I'm trying to use a coordinate pair (x, y) as a key for a table.  Here is what I have done so far

```
local test = {_props = {}}
local mt = {}
local xMax = 5
local yMax = 5

local function coord2index(x, y)
    return ((x-1) * xMax) + y
end

mt.__index = function(s, k)
    if s._props[coord2index(k[1], k[2])] ~= nil then
        return s._props[coord2index(k[1], k[2])]
    end
end

mt.__newindex = function(s, k, v)
   s._props[coord2index(k[1], k[2])] = v 
end
mt.__call = function (t, k)
    if type(k) == "table" then print "Table" end
end

setmetatable(test, mt)

test[{1,2}] = 5
print( test[{1,2}])
```

This is actually working as expected.  What I'm really wondering if there is a way to reduce this even more, something like `test[1,2] = 5` and `print(test[1,1])`.  There is no technical need for this, it's purely for my further edification into Lua.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your method is good. You can also use strings instead of numbers and do something like `return x..';'..y` in your `coord2index` function.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but wouldn't that just swap the brackets for quotes?  If I understand what your suggesting you mean that I would do something like `test["1,2"] = 5` and `print(test["1,2"])`? Or am I being dense and missing something?

Comment: Yes, but in your case 1 and 2 are variables. Sure you (as the user) can write `test[a..';'..b]`, but this exposes implementation details to the user. In your implementation you've hidden those details that's why I suggested using the same mechanism, just a different format for the key.

Comment: With Lua 5.3 integers this code may lead to strange result :)

Comment: `x..';'..y` this code depend of number type (integer/float) and it is not easy to trace this type. e.g. old C code could use lua_pushnumber to pass coordinates to Lua and other part use e.g. number literal. I think if coordinates is integer code should use floor/ceil/round or use string.format("%g;%g",...) to ensure that numbers is integer.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko That is an interesting approach, I wonder how it would compare against mine (using a table) as far as utilizing.  I'll have to do some testing when I get a chance.  I feel that the strings would be easier to pass back and forth, as well as generate on the fly.