# Lua 3d table lacks object permanence (key values do not consistently match to table data)

Tags: lua

So I'm having a bit of a strange problem with Lua, I use the following functions to setup, read and write from a global 3D "array" called Cube. However it seems that every time I am reading or writing to this "array", the data is only stored on the instance used by the function, despite Cube being a global variable, can't say I have ever encountered this before, very strange.

```
-- stole this one from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27976526/using-a-coordinate-pair-as-a-key-in-a-lua-table
-- basically the intended use is to store a 2d table of block information for the level the turtle is on

function setUpLevel()
    local test = {_props = {}}
    local mt = {}


    local function coord2index(x, z)
        return ((x-1) * xMax) + z
    end

    mt.__index = function(s, k)
        if s._props[coord2index(k[1], k[2])] ~= nil then
            return s._props[coord2index(k[1], k[2])]
        end
    end

    mt.__newindex = function(s, k, v)
    s._props[coord2index(k[1], k[2])] = v 
    end
    mt.__call = function (t, k)
        if type(k) == "table" then print "Table" end
    end

    setmetatable(test, mt)
    return test
    --test[{1,2}] = 5
end

function setupCube()
    local cube = {}
    cube[relY]=setUpLevel()
    return cube
end

Cube = setupCube()

function readCubeData(x,y,z)
    if (Cube[y]==nil) then
        return nil
    end
    -- debug
    return Cube[y][{x,z}]
end

function storeCubeData(x,y,z,data)
    if (readCubeData(x,y,z)==nil) then
        Cube[y]=setUpLevel()
    end



    Cube[y][{x,z}]=data
    data= readCubeData(x,y,z)
    print (x,",",y,",",z,":",readCubeData(x,y,z))
    sleep(.5)
end
```

Output Examples:

The print statements in `storeCubeData()` would provide the correct output of (order doesn't matter, just corresponding data to x,y,z values)
[image: Image showing the output from readCubeData() function when used within storeCubeData()]

However the following print statements in `start()`

```
function start()
    detectAndStore()
    print("=============")
    sleep(1)
    data= readCubeData(0,relY,1)
    print (0,",",relY,",",1,":",readCubeData(0,relY,1))
    sleep(.5)
    data= readCubeData(-1,relY,0)
    print (-1,",",relY,",",0,":",readCubeData(-1,relY,0))
    sleep(.5)
    data= readCubeData(0,y,-1)
    print (0,",",relY,",",-1,":",readCubeData(0,relY,-1))
    sleep(.5)
    data= readCubeData(1,y,0)
    print (1,",",relY,",",0,":",readCubeData(1,relY,0))
    sleep(.5)
end
start()
```

would produce an output of [image: Output from start() function, incorrect output, mismatch between x,y,z values and data which is supposed to be in it]

which is just tragically incorrect, the x,y,z values do not point to the correct values and also tables are not meant to be repeated in the same x,y,z location. I seriously can't for the life of me figure this out

Comment: Try `local function coord2index(x, z) return x..";"..z end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in `if (readCubeData(x,y,z)==nil) then` in `storeCubeData(x,y,z,data)`. You overwrite the entire 'level' every time you try to store new information in it. It should be `if (Cube [y] == nil) then`. The whole `if` statement can be further reduced to `Cube [y] = Cube [y] or setUpLevel ()`.

Also, `if s._props[coord2index(k[1], k[2])] ~= nil then` is not necessary; and the functions can be defined as local; and the hash function `coord2index` will cause collisions (e.g. `coord2index (1, 5) == coord2index (2, -5)`, if `xMax == 10`), so replace it as @Egor Skriptunoff said.